# yocto: failing to find Python.h and cross compiling fails

Tags: gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, yocto, openembedded

Im using poky version of yocto, and adding zbar library in my yocto build. I found a readymade recipe at http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/zbar/zbar_0.10.bb and modified it a bit to get working with poky. I got it working fine with imagemagick, and the compiled zbarimg works on the target board.

The modified recipe is available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25725000/

When I proceed configuring python support (`--with-python`) to the build, some dependency issues crept up, which Im unable to resolve.

It appears as if the compiler doesn't find the appropriate headers, since the include paths don't contain appropriate folder.

The full compiler command is:

`arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: compile:  arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/jlumme/imx_build/build-x11-pico-imx6ul/tmp/sysroots/pico-imx6ul-emmc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/jlumme/imx_build/build-x11-pico-imx6ul/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/zbar/0.10-r0/zbar-0.10 -I./include -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/jlumme/imx_build/build-x11-pico-imx6ul/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/zbar/0.10-r0/zbar-0.10/include -Wall -Wno-parentheses -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -c /home/jlumme/imx_build/build-x11-pico-imx6ul/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/zbar/0.10-r0/zbar-0.10/python/symbol.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o python/.libs/python_zbar_la-symbol.o`

You can see that `sysroot` variable is set, and it appears like the right location, and there is `/usr/include/python2.7` there, though its pointing right at the host system include path.

There is a warning from compiler: `cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/python2.7" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]` which I don't know why it happens, but it seems like the `python2.7` folder is appropriately looked at, just not under the `sysroot` (my host system doesn't have /usr/lib/python2.7)

If I go to the sysroot include (`/home/jlumme/imx_build/build-x11-pico-imx6ul/tmp/sysroots/pico-imx6ul-emmc/usr/include/`) folder, I can see that it has a subfolder `python2.7`. If under this usr/include folder I add a symlink `Python.h -> python2.7/Python.h`, the compiler will complain about the next header file which is not found.

So to me it seems, all I should do is add the appropriate `'sysroot'` + `usr/include/python2.7` as include search folder it would compile happily - but Im not sure how..

The full compilation log is available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25725014/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the zbar configure script.

Try inheriting pythonnative so the configure script can run a compatible Python to know where to look.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for the reply. I added the dependency to the zbar config file (http://paste.ubuntu.com/25751634/ <-modified DEPENDS), but I still get same include dependency, and it fails in the same way.. 
How could I confirm that the change actually changes something in the way configuration is executed ? Im fairly new to yocto, so I might do something silly

Comment: While modifying the DEPENDS did not seem to help, I just added bluntly `CFLAGS += "-I${STAGING_INCDIR}/python2.7"` to zbar's config file, and it compiled - however, after that I get some "QA errors" complaining about `Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package`, and the files pointed out were `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zbar.la` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zbar.so` (and also .debug versions)..